# Automatically propagate controller and model code changes to my views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When I make changes to controller methods, models/view models, I get the prompt to propagate the changes throughout the code base. This is working as intended for C# code. But my views are not updated too, so I end up having to chase down everything manually, which can be a pill with a lot of partials.

Is there something I can do to ease this process (other than not making changes)? I do have Resharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

That is normal functioning. The Views must be modified manually.

One thing that will help is to use ReSharper's Find Code Issues. It will point out all views that aren't compiling properly, so at least you will know what Views to look in.